# mobile friendly resized images

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How would I go about creating a mobile-friendly image that has been manually resized to fit the desktop version?

Example:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <%= image_tag("Sample_Mach.png", :alt => "Sample pack cover, album art", :width => 300, :height => 300) %>
</div>
```

300px is too big for mobile versions, yet I've tried to make it take after the `col-md-4` class via `inherit` but it loads the image strangely (too big on mobile, too small on desktop). I've tried using `%` but it loads it at 100% of its original file resolution (still too big).

Comment: Bootstrap already have a default class for responsive image  .img-responsive [ https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_images.asp ]
If you are using bootstrap version 4.0.0  then use class img-fluid 
[ https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/ ]

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Can you give this to me as an answer so I can give you some rep?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap already have a default class for responsive image .img-responsive [w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_images.asp](http://w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_images.asp).

If you are using bootstrap version 4.0.0 then use class img-fluid. [getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images)